# What's the difference in `any[]` and `{ [s: string]: any }`?

Tags: typescript

I was trying to get this code to work:

```
test(a: any[]) {
    let b: string[][] = [];
    b.push(Object.keys(a[0]));
    b.push(...a.map(e => Object.values(e)));
  }
```

but the compiler doesn't like the `b.push(...a.map(e => Object.values)));` line: "TS2345: Argument of type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.   Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'"

But this same code works if I change the parameter type to `test(a: { [s: string]: any }) {` which I kinda just figured out by luck.

My question(s):

- Why does it work with the weird type?
- what does that weird type even mean? it reads like gibberish to me, it's an object of keys (of type array???) which map to `any`?
- when calling `a.map(e =>` it infers the type of e to be `e?: any` without the weird type, and it infers as `e: any` with the special signature. What does `e?: any` mean?

Comment: `{ [s: string]: any }` does not work without `noImplicitAny` set to `false`: https://tsplay.dev/WyXPxm

Comment: It actually *doesn't* work with your weird type. You get errors with `noImplicitAny` set to `true`. Even if you fix it, it's not the desired behavior. `{ [s: string]: any }` is *essentially* any **object**, and `any[]` is *essentially* any **array**.

Comment: Your weird type, again, is any object. Or at least, any object with strings for keys that can hold any value (so basically any object).

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior in your last question with the playground above. Anyways, that's all your questions addressed. If I didn't address something, mention me here and I'll do my best to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what does that weird type even mean?

You refer to type `{ [s: string]: any }`, it is an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures):

> Sometimes you don’t know all the names of a type’s properties ahead of time, but you do know the shape of the values.
>
> In those cases you can use an index signature to describe the types of possible **values**

(emphasis mine)

As mentioned by kelly in the question comments, it describes an object, with little information about its properties, but the *values* of these properties are of type `any`.

---

> Why does it work with the weird type?

Actually, it "works" if you rather type the argument `a` as an *array* of this type:

```
function test2(a: { [s: string]: any }[]) { // Typed `a` as an array of objects with the "weird" type
  let b: string[][] = [];
  b.push(Object.keys(a[0]));
  b.push(...a.map(e => Object.values(e)));
  //              ^? (parameter) e: { [s: string]: any; }
}
```

`a` being an array, the compiler knows that `a.map` iterates on the items of that array. And the items are objects which values are `any`, which is assignable to `string`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygJgBQEMBciA3ogNpqEYBOMYA5gLqG5gCeiAvqQwJTECwAKESIANiiiIARpSg163bogC8ZBgG4hIqQDoADiDQALbAHkpAKxTQdAaxSs0eUgAZePTcOn7DJnf9wdAFtcPWwUFQA+RHMrGwA3XFEQdHCedM8RAHoskTz8goA9AH4hDiEhUEhYBGR0KDxmNm4+Ii0xCWlZeTpFBhU1TO8DYzNLayg7BydcV3ch3RG-AODQ8KiY8YSklKcUdI92nIKTvJKyoSA)